# modify .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to web development. In my site I have public_html folder and it has the app folder. I have following RewriteRule in my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Now I want to modify the rule such a way that if I create new  folder profile under public_html than it should display the index.php of the profile folder. Basically, If I type www.example.com/profile in browser window, it should display the content of index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this, but this should be the simplest way for you.

RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9_-]+/?$ ./profile/index.php [L,NC]

Comment: Do I need to add after the original rules? something like this RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^$ app/webroot/    [L] RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9_-]+/?$ ./profile/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]